# Attempt to index field (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I am trying to make simple object container in Lua ( to practice a language a little)

```
Container = {}
Container.__index = Container

function Container.create( maxNumber )
   local c = {}             -- our new object
   setmetatable(c, Container)
   c.maxNumberOfRecords = maxNumber
   c.cont = {}
   return c
end

function Container:add(index, val)
         self.cont[index] = val
end

function Container:getAt(index)
    return self.cont[index]
end

return Container
```

but I always get error `Attempt to index field 'cont' (a nil value)` when I try to add to container. Can anyone tell me what is a problem ?
I am totally new to lua but I looked at code at documentation http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show an example of code that does not work? It looks OK to me:

```
> Container = require "Container"
> c = Container.create(5)
> c:add(2, 42)
> =c:getAt(2)
42
```

Comment: Thank you, I am stupid, I have habit from Java/Python to call function with . and not :. That was mistake